# Colorear columnas de chart C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, charts

Estoy cargando una grafica de barras y quiero que pasando de 45 que esa columna se ponga en color rojo el resto queda en color Negro

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)//recorro el datatable 
            {
                string qty = dt.Rows[i]["Cant"].ToString();//obtengo la cantidad
                if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//comparo
                {
                    chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Black;
                }
               
            }
  chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = 
  System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
    
            chart1.DataSource = dt;
            chart1.DataBind();
```

Cuando depuro si pasa por el `if`, o sea, si pasa por el color rojo pero, cuando se completa de cargar los datos, todas las columnas quedan en color negro.

Comment: Si asignas el tipo de Series antes del for te sucede lo mismo?

Comment: @Bicho pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Puedes poner el código entero del método?asinas las series de manera gráfica antes?

Comment: Agregué una respuesta a tu problema y además vote por tu pregunta, por que me parece un buen ejemplo, de  lógica elemental, independiente del problema y del lenguaje de programación que estes usando.

Answer (score 0):

No se nada de manejo de gráfica de barras, pero lo único que se es que en tu código en los dos casos, se cumpla o no se cumpla la condición `Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45`, haces lo mismo, solo haces `chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.el_que_sea;`, debes de estudiar cual es la forma de acceder a cada items o no se como se llame de tu objeto `chart1` de otra forma, no haces nada con recorrer todas las filas de tu objeto dt, para en cada iteración asignar valor al mismo objeto.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)//recorro el datatable 
 {
     string qty = dt.Rows[i]["Cant"].ToString();//obtengo la cantidad
   if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//comparo
    {
      //Le asignas color rojo al objeto chart1.Series["Series1"] 
      chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
      //Y aquí le asignas color negro al mismo objeto chart1.Series["Series1"]
      chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Black;
    }

}
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = 
      System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

chart1.DataSource = dt;
chart1.DataBind();
```

Este es un tema de lógica elemental, que nada tiene que ver con el funcionamiento del objeto `chart1`; cuando menos si cada ítem `Series` se llamara "Series1" "Series2", "Series3" y así hasta N "SeriesN",

```
       for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)//recorro el datatable 
         {
             string qty = dt.Rows[i]["Cant"].ToString();//obtengo la cantidad
           if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//comparo
            {
              //Le asignas color rojo al objeto chart1.Series["Series"+i.ToString()] 
             chart1.Series["Series"+i.ToString()].Color = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
              //Y aquí le asignas color negro al objeto chart1.Series["Series"+i.ToString()] ya no es el mismo
              chart1.Series["Series"+i.ToString()].Color = Color.Black;
            }


        chart1.Series["Series"+i.ToString()].ChartType = 
              System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;
 }      
        chart1.DataSource = dt;
        chart1.DataBind();
```

Se trata de que en cada iteración hagas referencia a un objeto `Series` diferente, reconozco que no se si es la forma correcta de hacer la referencia, pero lo que si se es que nunca puede ser la misma en cada iteración.

Answer (score 0):

El código que tienes cambia el color de la serie completa y no es lo que buscas.

Puedes dar color a las barras de manera individual utilizando el atributo `items` de la serie, por ejemplo:

```
  chart1.DataSource = dt;
  chart1.DataBind();
  chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Black;
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
    if (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Cant"].ToString()) > 45) {
      chart1.Series["Series1"].Items[i].MainColor = Color.Red;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba a limpiar series cada vez que recorre el bucle y  volver a crearlo. Ten en cuenta que es si tienes asignadas más propiedades de series1 deberás añadirlas también después de añadir la serie. Debería funcionarte pues no tienes creada la serie antes de una condición u otra.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count;i++)
{

 chart1.Series.clear(); //limpias el chart

 string qty = dt.Rows[i]["Cant"].ToString();//obtengo la cantidad
   if (Convert.ToInt32(qty) > 45)//comparo
   {

   chart1.Series.Add("Series1); //creas Series1 


  chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
   }
  else
{

 chart1.Series.Add("Series1);// crear series1


  chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Black;
}

}
chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = 

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SerieChartType.Column;

  chart1.DataSource = dt;
  chart1.DataBind();
```